# Intel Graphics Installer failed

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

```
CPU: Intel i5-3437U (4) @ 2.900GHz 
GPU: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
```

I get this error when I run the following command.

```
$ intel-linux-graphics-installer 
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking if Intel graphics card available...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Retrieving information from 01.org...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking distribution...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking kernel version...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking available repositories...
diagnostics-view.c/new_diagnostic: Adding diagnostic for Checking package manager status...
No LSB modules are available.
polkit: Fetching org.01.linuxgraphics.installer permissions...
diagnostics-view.c/diagnostics_view_start: Running diagnostic Checking if Intel graphics card available...
diagnostics-view.c/diagnostics_view_start: Running diagnostic Retrieving information from 01.org...
{
  errors: (nil)
  sources: []
  keys: []
  docs: []
  INSTALL: []
  install: []
  upgrade: []
}
diagnostics-view.c/diagnostics_view_start: Running diagnostic Checking distribution...
 package_manager_is_distro_supported
 Configuration : Loading …  [   0 % ] ⏲
{
  errors: (nil)
  sources: []
  keys: []
  docs: []
  INSTALL: []
  install: []
  upgrade: []
}
 package_manager_is_distro_supported
 Configuration : Loaded  [  80 % ] ⏲
 package_manager_is_distro_supported
 Configuration : Testing …  [  80 % ] ⏲
 package_manager_is_distro_supported
 Configuration : Complete  [  ] ◦
```

[image: screenshot]

```
  > sudo lshw -c video
  
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1366,768
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Sorry what error? What version and kernel of Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you not have the i915 driver which is the correct default. Post this in question above. `sudo lshw -c video`

Comment: You really don't need to install a driver, support for your Intel integrated GPU is built into the kernel and Xorg.

Comment: please post the output of this sudo lshw -c video

Comment: I also added the output of the `sudo lshw -c video` command.